# MongoDB insert raises duplicate key error

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

I am getting the following error when trying to do a bulk insert into an *empty* mongodb collection.

> pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error index:
>   cmdDistros.locDistro.$*id*  dup key: { :
>   ObjectId('51dac9d0c74cd81acd85c0fd') }

I am not specifying an _id when I create any of the documents, so mongodb should create the unique index correct?  Here is the code I used:

```
#Populate database with uniform distribution
            entries = []
            for coor in freeIndices:
                for theta in range(360):
                    entry = {"x" : coor[0], "y" : coor[1], "heading" : theta}
                    for i in range(numData):
                            entry["data" + str(i)] = 1./numData
                    entries.append(entry)
            print "Entries created, loading into database..."

            locDistro.insert(entries)
```

Taking fate out of mongoDB's hands, I tried creating my own index using:

```
#Populate database with uniform distribution
            entries = []
            idNum = 0
            for coor in freeIndices:
                for theta in range(360):
                    print idNum
                    entry = {"_id" : idNum, "x" : coor[0], "y" : coor[1], "heading" : theta}
                    idNum += 1
                    for i in range(numData):
                            entry["data" + str(i)] = 1./numData
                    entries.append(entry)
            print "Entries created, loading into database..."

            locDistro.insert(entries, manipulate = False)
```

The print statement showed each idnum as the documents were created, and they were all unique and incremented just as expected.  However on insert, I received the error:

> pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error index:
>   cmdDistros.locDistro.$*id*  dup key: { : 0 }

and only one document was inserted into my database.

I am completely stumped, anyone have an answer as to why this might be happening?

Comment: I don't know what happened, but the problem has somehow managed to fix itself...I just ran the code over and over and it just worked....weird..if anyone has an explanation I would still want to know just in case it happens again...and by the way, the entries.append line is a typo, the actual position is aligned with the for above it.

Comment: are there any other indexes defined in the collection?

Comment: None.  Just _id.  I would like to use ensure_index to create an index on x y and heading, but they aren't unique so I am not sure if that would work.  Regardless only _id is indexed at this point.

Comment: are the two options working now? _id created by the driver and _id created by yourself.

Comment: The _id created by the driver is working now, I have not retried creating my own _ids, and experience has left me wary of touching code after I know it works.

Comment: how did you create locDistro object ? By the way you should be able to uncheck the accept flag by clicking on it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to understand that your entries list has a bunch of references to **one** entry dict. So when PyMongo sets entries[0]['_id'], all the other entries get the same _id. (In fact, PyMongo will iterate through the list setting each entry's _id, so all the entries will have the **final** _id at the end.) A quick fix would be:

```
entries.append(entry.copy())
```

This is merely a shallow copy, but in the code you shared I believe this is enough to fix your problem.

Comment: the entry is being created on every loop, how can be they pointing to same object? I think this is not the correct answer

Comment: I am stuck with this weird behavior of pymongo 's `insert_one` as well. I heard both the `copy` method and the `del obj['_id']` method. I still don't get the copy method though. Do I have to make a copy too for each object I insert although the object is different?

Comment: This answer also applies to NodeJS when inserting multiple objects with the same reference lol. Thanks

Comment: This fixed my issue however i'm still not clear on why this should be the case. entry is initialized on each iteration, before appended to entries. something weird going on

Answer (score 10):

Delete the key `"_id"`:

```
for i in xrange(2): 
    doc['i'] = i 
    if '_id' in doc: 
        del doc['_id'] 
    collection.insert(doc)
```

Or manually create a new one:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

for i in xrange(2): 
    doc['i'] = i 
    doc['_id'] = ObjectId() 
    collection.insert(doc)
```

[Getting "err" : "E11000 duplicate key error when inserting into mongo using the Java driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119928/getting-err-e11000-duplicate-key-error-when-inserting-into-mongo-using-the)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error using `insert_one()` and also `insert_many()`

My solution is, to use `update_one()` with `upsert=True`

```
  doc = {a: 1, b:2, x:{xx:"hello",yy:"world"}}
  db.collection.update_one(doc,{'$set':doc},upsert=True)
```

This works for me :-)

Comment: This one is very nice. Worked for me.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

**Make sure variable 'entries' is cleared after every insert.**

The problem is that PyMongo injects an **_id** field into the document, if the **_id** field does not exist, before inserting it (**_id** is always generated client side). That means that the first time through the loop **_id** is added by the insert method. Since *'entries'* is defined outside, each subsequent pass through the loop uses the same value for **_id**.

**Clear the dict variable in top of the loop statements.**

OR

**Remove _id from the dict. Eg:**

```
del my_dict['_id']
```

Comment: This answer explains the `why` of the issue. I first could not believe that `insert_xxx` mutates its arguments but for some weird reason it does.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION: Declare dict() item inside the loop and then populate and insert it.**
I had a similar problem while using **insert_one()** from **pymongo**. I solved my problem by declaring the **dict()** item inside the loop.
Here is the working version of your code:

```
#Populate database with uniform distribution
            entries = []
            for coor in freeIndices:
                for theta in range(360):
                    entry = dict()
                    entry['x'] = coor[0]
                    entry['y'] = coor[1]
                    entry['heading'] = theta
             
                    for i in range(numData):
                            entry['data' + str(i)] = 1./numData
                    entries.append(entry)
            print "Entries created, loading into database..."

            locDistro.insert(entries)
```