# How to create a unique `_id` for each db.collection.insert_one(doc) in MongoDB running in Azure?

Tags: python, mongodb, azure, duplicates, insert

```
class MongoABC:
    def __init__(self):
    # all the variable initialisation    
    ...

    def insert_to_mongo(self, user_id, json):
        self.db.collection.insert_one(json)
```

If I create an instance of `MongoABC` and call the `insert_to_mongo` function more than once, it generates a **E11000 duplicate key error** on the `_id`.

It performs it in real time so previous solutions of making a copy of inserting document(`json`), upserting it or deleting the `_id` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529216/mongodb-insert-raises-duplicate-key-error) doesn't seem to work in this case.
The `_id` always remain constant as long as the `MongoABC` instance is same. So how do we create an unique `_id` for every time we call `insert_one()`?

This error is specific to mongo servers running in Microsoft azure.

Comment: Can you show an example of the `json` object you are inserting? It appears you are using the [pymongo](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html?highlight=insert_one#inserting-a-document) driver. Which version are you using?

Comment: @MattKneiser Upgrading the version to the latest helped with the solutions that weren't working before. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create id for mongo db. Once document is inserted, id is automatically generated. You can check id by this snippet.

```
obj = db[collection].insert_many(json)
print(obj.inserted_ids)
```